# Widths of footer/ navigation at 100% not equal to widths of header/ container at 100%

Tags: mobile, responsive-design

I'm building a website (summer-band.com) and trying to tweak the mobile settings (browser at < 600px) with 100% width settings for several of the elements. Unfortunately, with what I've done so far, the header/ container and the navigation bar as well as the footer all seem to be shooting out different widths and I can't seem to fix this on my own, thus asking for some assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the menu: `#navigation li a` and `#navigation li.current_page_item a`'s `width` is `100%` but has a padding, so the box model won't do what you want. The `width` should be `auto`. This is a recurring problem of yours.

Next, the header: You have `#headerImg`'s `width` set to a constant `600px`. In your media query, you'll probably want to make the `width` and `height` `auto` and make the actual `img`'s `width` `100%`.

Moving down, your main `#box` has a `width` of `100%` and a padding. Due to the box model, this probably won't do what you want. Make the `width` `auto`.

Further down, your `#footer` has a `display` of `inline-block` and a `width` of `100%`. You'll probably want to change its `display` to `block` and `width` to `auto`.

I think that's mostly it, but you might want to set `article img`'s `max-width` to `100%` and remove the explicit `width` on your Kickstarter screenshot. I don't really know how to deal with the `iframe` with the video. Sorry.

A few last comments: You seem to be overusing `br`s and empty `p` tags rather than using appropriate `margin`s.

Comment: Thank you so very much. I'm still in the learning stages with a lot of things, so your feedback helps greatly and I really appreciate it.